# Using ASP.NET Core 2.0 to update live data in Views

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core, razor-pages

As far as I understand when the server process a client request (example a GET) it will run through the Razor/Controller code to generate the html page to return.

In my page I display a table with data read from my model. Right now I'm able to:

- update the whole page when new data are available
- use Ajax and some Javascript to "live" update the items on my View

I'm wondering if there's a "native" way to do this, without using Ajax manually.
Something where when I change the model data, the related values on the View are automatically updated.

Most important is if it's possible to do this server side, without continuously polling like in the Ajax solution.

### EDIT

Someone downvoted the question. I guess because it has labelled as "too broad".
Well, I try to ask a more narrow question then.

"How to update a specific value on a View, when a `DbSet` or a `List<>` change, without polling back from the client.`

Comment: How about something like [`WebSockets`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets)?

Comment: I'm going to give it a try, seems to fit quite close to my needs, even it's still handled manually, anyway.

Comment: I don't understand the prerequisites. I'm running the example in Windows 7 with the IIS Server that comes with VisualStudio 2017. It always returns `IsWebSocketRequest = false`. This is because it needs Windows 8?

Comment: My interpretation is that if you want to use IIS, you need Windows 8/IIS 8. Otherwise (say if you're using Kestrel directly, for example), it seems it'll work as is. Try the example project that's included in the dosc page I linked, if you haven't already. I'm on Windows 10 so can't try it out for you.

Comment: As said, I've already tried it but it returns always false for that property. Unfortunately I can't change the environment.

Comment: Sorry, I slightly misread your reference to the example. Have you been able to try it without using IIS?

Comment: No, because the target environment will be Window 7 with IIS, so it's not suitable for this project.

Comment: No, it's too broad because you are asking how to write some code instead of "I wrote this code, it doesn't work, how do I fix it". On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Comment: Ok, but how I might post a complete example if I don't know the right functions/libraries to write it? I understand you always ask for a verifiable example but it cannot be applied to every scenario. I'm not lazy, nor I'm asking you to do my homework...

Comment: And, therefore, your question is off topic. Too many people think SO is just like every other forum. It's not.

Comment: You may want to check SignalR. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/09/14/announcing-signalr-for-asp-net-core-2-0/

Comment: @OzgurGUL but it's already available for ASP.NET Core? it's still in alpha... and I downloaded a test project but it returns always 204 (it seems it use websockets as well)

Comment: Yeah, it's available for Core 2 and may not be used in production but it works.